How to solve for the matrix $A$ given two vectors $x$,$y$ and the equation $Ax=y$
Motivation: Following https://arxiv.org/pdf/1904.11782.pdf, and trying to modify the result for triangles with angle 120 degrees, everything is the same up until section 4.
All primitive solutions to $x^2+xy+y^2=z^2$ (this corresponds to a triangle of 120 degrees) are of the form
\begin{equation}
x=m^2-n^2\\
y=2mn+n^2\\
z=m^2+mn+n^2
\end{equation}
where $n<m$, $\gcd(m,n)=1$, and $m\not\equiv n\pmod{3}$. They are also generated uniquely. This slightly differs to the 60 degree triangle case, but for both, we are looking for reduced fractions $0<n/m<1$ with $m\not\equiv n\pmod{3}$. Hence it helps to look at the Stern-Brocot tree.
The author finds that you can replace the fraction in the Stern-Brocot tree by matrices. The matrices in the tree can then related via $6$ transformation matrices.
For example, one transformation matrix is,
$$A_1=\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 \\
    3 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$
It has the effect of taking the fraction $n/m$ to $n/(3n+m)$ corresponding to the triangle with sides $((3n+m)^2-n^2,2(3n+m)n+n^2,m^2+mn+n^2)$.
Question: Thus we went from a solution $(x,y,z)$ with corresponding values $(n,m)$, applied $A_1$ and obtained a new solution $(x',y',z')$ with corresponding values $(n,3n+m)$. What is the matrix $M_1$ such that $\begin{bmatrix}x' \\ y' \\ z' \end{bmatrix}=M_1\begin{bmatrix}x \\ y \\ z \end{bmatrix}$
The author states that (in the case of the 60 degree triangle)
$$M_1=\begin{bmatrix}
7 & -6 & 6\\
8&-7&7 \\
4&-4&3
\end{bmatrix}$$
which can be verified to hold, but how did they do this?

I wrote programs to solve, all in integer matrices, $P^T H P = G$   where $G,H$ are  given symmetric integer. For indefinite quadratic forms ( some eigenvalues positive, some negative) I also tell the program an upper bound on the absolute values of the elements of $P.$  The tricky  "automorphisms" are $P^T H P = H.$ Easy to brute force find a few such $P.$  Usually hard to produce the entire group and prove that you have them all. One case that is proved is $x^2 + y^2 - z^2.$  I expect this form $x^2 + xy + y^2 - z^2$ can be completed as well

Alright, his $M_1;$    we have $M_1^T H M_1 = H$   for  $$  H =
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
-2 & 0 & 0 \
0 & 2 & -1 \
0 & -1 & 2 \
\end{array}
\right)
$$

@WillJagy Cool approach! Do you have an reference to this program that I can use? Also do you think this is the method Zimhoni used?

The equation $Ax = y$ is formally inverted by setting $A = \frac{yx^T}{\|x\|^2}$, where the denominator $\|x\|^2 = \langle x,x \rangle = x^Tx$ only accounts for normalization purposes. Indeed, one can check easily that $Ax = y\frac{x^Tx}{\|x\|^2} = y$. Note that the product $yx^T$ has to be understood as the usual matricial multiplication, hence for instance in two dimensions :
$$
A = \frac{yx^T}{\|x\|^2} = \frac{\begin{pmatrix} y_1 \\ y_2 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} x_1 & x_2 \end{pmatrix}}{\left\|\begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{pmatrix}\right\|^{2}} = \frac{1}{x_1^2+x_2^2} \begin{pmatrix} x_1y_1 & x_2y_1 \\ x_1y_2 & x_2y_2 \end{pmatrix}
$$

Fixed minor typo, also I can't seem to apply this to my problem. I get a jumble of $n$'s and $m$'s not the $M_1$ above.

This diagram is in the published article; the forest is two trees, from those roots there are five branches each.

